# Change text of a cell on dataGridView_CellFormatting

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a `Datagridview` column with a value as `int`. I have a condition for the value status, `if(status == 1)` then change text to `Active`, else change text to `Not Active`.

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
private void bindListToGridView(List<Employee> list)
{
     // DataTable dt2 = convertListToDataTable(list);
     // more codes here.
     using (dt2)
     {
        // more codes here.
        dataGridView1.Columns[8].Name = "Status";
        dataGridView1.Columns[8].HeaderText = "Status";
        dataGridView1.Columns[8].DataPropertyName = "status";

       dataGridView1.DataSource = dt2;
     }
 }
private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    string columnName = dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name;
    if (columnName == "Status")
    {
        int value = (int)dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Status"].Value;
        if (value == 1)
        {
           // set the cell text = Active
        }
        else
        {
            // set the cell text = Not Active
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid changing the underlying integer value, you can set the cell's format to the desired text:

```
if (value == 1)
{
    dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Status"].Style.Format = "Active";
}
else
{
    dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Status"].Style.Format = "Not Active";
}
```

Or more easily, as LarsTech pointed out, just equivalently set:

```
e.Value = "Active";
```

This works because we are already in the `CellFormatting` event handler and the `Value` property of `DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs` is the formatted converted value.

Comment: I think you want `e.Value = "Active";` instead.

Comment: @LarsTech Thanks! I was so focused on avoiding the mistake of setting `cell.Value` that I quickly jumped to `cell.Style.Format` and overlooked the event args.